# How to handle attributes in interceptor binding

Tags: java, java-ee-6, interceptor

I have an annotation:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface Example {
}
```

And a interceptor class for its handling:

```
@Interceptor
@Example
public class ExampleInterceptor implements Serializable {
...
}
```

I would like to add a parameter text:

```
public @interface Example {
    String text();
}
```

But I don't know how to handle the parameter in the interceptor class. How to modify the annotation of the class?

```
@Interceptor
@Example(text=???????)
public class ExampleInterceptor implements Serializable {
...
}
```

If I write `@Example(text="my text")`, the interceptor is called just when a method/class is annotated with `@Example(text="my text")`. But I want the interceptor to be called independetly on a parameter value - `@Example(text="other text")`.

And how to get the parameter value? Do I have to use reflexion or is there a better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The interceptor is called for every attribute value when annotation `@Nonbinding` is used.

Annotation:

```
public @interface Example {
    @Nonbinding String text() default "";
}
```

Interceptor:

```
@Interceptor
@Example
public class ExampleInterceptor implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: For getting value of annotation on intercepted method in interceptor:

InvocationContext ctx;
Example example = ctx.getMethod().getAnnotation(Example.class);
String value = example.value();

Comment: What if I don't want to add a default method to force all uses of the annotation to specify a value? In my case, it's an enum value instead of a string, so it makes little sense to put @Example(MyEnum.SPECIFIC_VALUE) on the interceptor class.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you only have one parameter you can name it `value` and can then skip the parameter name (default), => can skip the text= part, like:

```
@Example("my text") //instead of @Example(test="My text")
public class ...
```

To access an annotation you use the method `getAnnotation` on the `Class`, `Method`, `Field` or `Constructor` type that you have to get firs. Then you get an instance of the annotation that you can call your methods on.

```
Example example = getClass().getAnnotation(); //if you are inside the interceptor you can just use getClass(), but you have to get the class from somewhere
example.value(); //or example.text() if you want your annotation parameter to be named text.
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I still don't know how to write the annotation for the interceptor class. I can't write just @Example because it want's a parameter. If I write @Example("my text"), the interceptor is called just when a method/class is annotated with @Example("my text"). But I want the interceptor to be called independetly on parameter value - @Example("other text"). Should I use regular expression? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you know what I mean? Could you help me with this?